# Sharepoint search query to only show Site Pages (or a new Wiki library)

Tags: search, sharepoint-online

I've got a new SharePoint Teams site that I'll be building out as a knowledge repository. We'll be creating articles in the "Site Pages" area, though happy to use a new Wiki Page Library if that makes it easier.

I'm trying to amend the Search Query used in the "All" vertical, so that it shows only results from the Site Pages. To test this, I've created a word document in the documents section and named it "Apples WORD.docx" and a Wiki page called "Apples WIKI". When I search for "Apples", I should only see "Apples WIKI" in my results.

I can't seem to figure out the query required to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've got this working now.

First I renamed an existing managed property by doing the following.
Go to the Site Settings, then Under the 'Site Collection Administration' go to "Search Schema".
Find an available RefinableStringXX managed property; edit it and give it an Alias. Add a mapping to "ContentTypeID".

Back out to the Site Settings then under 'Web Designer Galleries' click on "Site content types".
Find "Wiki Pages" and click on it to find the Content Type ID (which was 0x010108).

Back out to the Site Settings then under 'Microsoft Search', click on "Configure Search Settings".
Click on Verticals, then double click on the vertical that you want to edit. Click the Edit button at the bottom of the page.
Click on 'Query' and enter the text "ContentTypeID:0x010108*"
Save the vertical.

By editing the "All" vertical, the default 'current site' search from the site's homepage now only shows Wiki Page articles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding the search vertical to the search navigation web part to set up a search page for displaying Site Pages.

Reference:[Change settings for the Search Navigation Web Part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-navigation-web-part)

Comment: I've looked at that option but the instructions say to "On the search results page, click the Settings menu, and then click Edit Page.". There's no edit page option.
I should mention that I'm a site owner, not a 365 Admin. Also I suspect those instructions are for the global search center, as that has the "everything, conversations, people, videos" verticals whereas the teams site search has "all, sites, news, images" verticals.

I do see that I can edit the query's used by those existing verticals, which is what I think I need to do.